# How to stop Microsoft Search Indexer at all

Tags: windows-search

After i saw that the Search indexer service eats all my performance on my C: drive, i just want it to stop so i disabled the service but it seems like this did not stop it. Together with the Search Protocol host it starts again and again. I moved the SearchDatabase to another SSD of mine to release some pressure from my windows drive, but it still eats around 20% CPU on idle.

So why did the Service starts even when i set it to disabled? Does this might connect to the SQL2016 service as i know it will use the Windows Search service if possible. This was no problem in the older editions of SQL server as a Pre-16 edition simply did not use the service. Did that changed?

Best wishes
JPB

Answer (score 0):

1. In explorer just go to your drive (c: or other), right click -> properties ... on bottom side you should see indexing ... uncheck it
2. Your best option is to cut down on the amount of data that you’re indexing—there’s usually no reason to index every single file on your drive. You’ll need to open up the Indexing Options through the Control Panel or Start Menu search box to make the changes.
   The first thing you should notice is the Pause button on this window, which can pause indexing for up to 15 minutes—useful if you’re trying to do something and Windows Search happens to be in overdrive mode, though it really shouldn’t since it only runs while your PC is idle.
   You’ll want to click the Modify button and then trim down the list of locations to just the ones you really need indexed.